# How can I correct this 'Incompatible Obj-c types' warning?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uiimage, incompatibletypeerror

Specifically the warning is: "Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSString *', expected 'struct UIImage *' when passing argument 4 of 'objectWithType:name:code:image' from distinct Objective-C type". It follows a line that looks like so:

```
[Object objectWithType:@"Type" name:@"Name" code:@"0001" image:@"image.png"],
```

So, I understand that I created the class `Object` to take type UIImage, but I am providing it with type NSString. Here's the problem: I don't know how to indicate the image differently than its file name.

(Apologies if this is a basic problem. I'm new to this and trying to look for solutions before posting here. Any help you can offer is appreciated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need an instance of `UIImage`, which you understand. So, the class method `imageNamed:` is typically used for this:

```
[Object objectWithType:@"Type" name:@"Name" code:@"0001" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Another option (since you are using all strings here) might be to rewrite your method so that it takes a name instead of an image and then create the image inside the method implementation. So you might define the method:

```
- (void)objectWithType:(NSString*)type name:(NSString*)name code:(NSString*)code imageName:(NSString*)imageName
{
  UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
  // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIImage imageNamed:]. Will only work for images that are part of your project.

```
[Object objectWithType:@"Type" name:@"Name" code:@"0001" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'image.png' is included in your project bundle, then you can do this to pass a UIImage instead of an NSString:

```
[Object objectWithType:@"Type" name:@"Name" code:@"0001" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```